# How to "understand" ENVIRON option socket programming supporting automatic login

Tags: c++, sockets, telnet

I have a server socket that can be connected to by users via `telnet`. All the politics of `telnet` aside. I'm trying to support the -a ("automatic login") option on my server. This page http://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet says:

> -a' Attempt automatic login. **Currently, this sends the user name via the USER variable of the ENVIRON option if supported by the remote system**. The name used is that of the current user as returned by getlogin(2) if it agrees with the current user ID, otherwise it is the name associated with the user ID.

I'm trying to understand (in C++) how I can "understand / support the ENVIRON option". Obviously this refers to the `getenv` & `getlogin` functions. But both `getenv` & `getlogin` is for the local user. So any information retrieved that way, would be specific to the user running the program on the server. Where as, I want the login information from the client connected via `telnet`.

How can I go about retrieving this information from the server side?

Comment: These are client options and the ways to retrieve login stated there are applicable to client side. As for in what exact way authentication information is transferred to server you can see related RFC (I suppose [rfc 2941](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2941)), use network traffic capture tools like tcpdump or [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and look in open source [implementations](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Inetutils).

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it from my Server program (in C++). I don't see how any of those things can help me do that.

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. The option is for client. On server side you can only read data sent by client. The way it is sent is specified in protocol documentation (rfc). You can sniff network traffic for client and server known to support this option to see what bytes are sent on wire. And most of implementations are open source - you can look directly in source code. Unfortunately I cannot help you with details, it's just common sense of how such issues are solved in easy way.

Comment: @frymode the more I look into this the more I think it is not possible. I think you're right. The only way for them to do it is via prompt / entering a username. If you would like, make an answer explaining why and I'll accept it.